# Adding Gradle support to Eclipse

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin, buildship

I want to add Gradle to Eclipse. My goal is to add Gradle management to dependencies of some Android projects which were built at the time using Eclipse and conversion to an Android Studio project doesn't end well.

I've installed the Buildship plugin into eclipse. I have added Gradle to the project by right clicking the project -> Configure -> Add Gradle Environment.

Now what? I don't see any Gradle files in the project where I can manage the dependencies.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do not use Eclipse for android developing, it's slow and lack of tools.
Also Eclipse support has ended by Google officially.

> With the release of Android Studio 2.2, the time has now come to say goodbye to the Eclipse Android Developer Tools. We have formally ended their support and development. There's never been a better time to switch to Android Studio and experience the improvements we've made to the Android development workflow.

[Source](http://android-developers.blogspot.com.tr/2016/11/support-ended-for-eclipse-android.html)

[This documentation](https://developer.android.com/studio/intro/migrate.html) is very helpful to migrate Android Studio from Eclipse. We cannot help without which migrating problems did you encountered while the process.

Also there are useful links for you:

[Gradle Integration for Eclipse](https://gradle.org/eclipse/)

[Gradle Plugin Documentation for Eclipse](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html)

[Useful Gradle Tutorial for Eclipse](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/EclipseGradle/article.html) - This one has the instructions needed in section 5. After completing section 5 with running gradle init, you should right click the project -> Gradle -> Refresh Gradle Project. Then the new Gradle files be added to your project.

Comment: I Know the support had ended and I have also stated that the conversion to AS projects did not end well for this project so for this one, I keep using Eclipse. I have installed the plugin and just need to understand how to use Gradle with Eclipse. How do I add the build.gradle file?

Comment: "Do not use Eclipse for android developing, it's slow" I can't believe you had guts to say that.